# How to pass updated state to a child component on rendering of the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJs. In the below code I am getting data by making API call when the page loads. And I populate the state property. And pass the state to both grid and list view. And that data I want to display in Grid or List component. But, the state property value is not changed and no value is passed to the child component `GridView` or `ListView` when the page is rendered. However the state property value get updated but I think the child component is rendered before it gets updated and that's why no value is passed to the child component. Is there a way to pass the updated sate property value on page load?

```
import GridView from './gridview/Grid';
import ListView from './listview/List';

export default class Home extends Component{

 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     value: this.props.value,
     propertyData: []
   }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   const success = fetch("http://Some api to get the data")
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => this.setState({propertyData: data}));
 }

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
   return {
     value: props
   }
 }

 GridOrList() {
   if(this.state.value.value) {
     return <GridView data={this.state.propertyData}/>
   }
   else {
     return <ListView data={this.state.propertyData}/>
   }

 }

 render() {
   return(
     <div>
       {this.GridOrList()}
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the components reliant on the state will be re-rendered once the state gets changed. You could use loader while your data from api is being fetched:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: this.props.value,
      propertyData: [],
      loading: true // Add loading state
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const success = fetch("http://Some api to get the data")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ propertyData: data, loading: false })); // Reset loading state
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {
      value: props
    };
  }

  GridOrList() {
    if (this.state.value.value) {
      return <GridView data={this.state.propertyData} />;
    } else {
      return <ListView data={this.state.propertyData} />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? (
      <p>Loading data...</p>
    ) : (
      <div>{this.GridOrList()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! I didnt understand though how did it happen? Just by adding loader it started working? Could you please explain me?

Comment: Delaying component rendering before the actual data is fetched can prevent cases when your components receive empty or incomplete state and do not render properly. I assume in this case one of your nested components is accessing some nested prop from `propertyData`, which doesn't exist until the api request is finished, so it was resulting in an error.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the GridOrList on the render function:

```js
 render() {
   return(
     <div>
       {this.state.value.value ? (
         <GridView data={this.state.propertyData}/>
       ):(
         <ListView data={this.state.propertyData}/>
       )}
     </div>
   )
 }
```

without `this.GridOrList()`

`this.setState` will update the state and execute the render function

Comment: did you check in your `GridView` or `ListView` the props, console the props on the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method if they are classes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
render() {
   return(
     <div>
       {this.state.value? ( --> // I think the problem is `this.state.value.value`
         <GridView data={this.state.propertyData}/>
         <ListView data={this.state.propertyData}/>
       ):null}
     </div>
   )
 }
```

As you can see here you're assigning `value` from props to the `value` key of your state:

```
this.state = {
     value: this.props.value,
     propertyData: []
}
```

I guess you will access it by `this.state.value` instead of `this.state.value.value`

Answer (score 0):

setState() is usually asynchronous, which means that at the time you console.log the state, it's not updated yet. Try putting the log in the callback of the setState() method. It is executed after the state change is complete:setState() takes time to mutate the value and you javascript is asynchronous and hence your console.log() will be executed before the setState mutates the values and hence you see the result.

check if the state is updated or not before rendering lists in the render function.

```
if(state.data !=null) {
   //create objects and render the array of objects in return function
}
```